# How to implement Regex in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have a doubt with a problem that I have to resolve in Java. The thing is: my program receives two arguments by console, the first one is the file's path where I have to load this file to the java program, It's a .ini file. The second argument is a code, with this pattern: XXX-XXXX or XXX-XXXX-XXXX where 'X' are numbers from 0 to 9. Here in the second argument my problem comes in: I have to use the packet java.util.regex to implement this pattern, I mean, I have to validate that the user input the arguments properly. How can I do this?
The part of my code that implements this is the following, thanks in advance:

```
Pattern patron = Pattern.compile("^[0-9]{3,}"); //aqui va la regex que queremos poner
    Matcher match = patron1.matcher(args[1]);


    if(args.length < 2){ // el programa espera recibir dos argumentos

        System.out.println("ERROR, número de argumentos inválido!");
        System.exit(1); //termina el programa
    } else if(args[0].endsWith("config.ini") == false){ //COMPLETAR la segunda condicion
        System.out.println("ERROR, los argumentos no toman valores válidos");
        System.exit(1);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

`if(args.length >= 2 && args[1] != null && args[1].matches("^\\d{3,}(\\-\\d{3,}){1,2}$"))`

`^` stands for start of the string

`\\d{3,}` a number repeating 3 or more times

`(\\-\\d{3,})` a group composed of a dash and the construct explained above

`{1,2}` means that group repeating between one and two times

`$` the end of the string

Comment: Please, would you explain me a little bit the regex that you used? Thanks a lot

Comment: @user71209 I've edited my answer to try to explain the regex. You can find a better explanation [HERE](https://regex101.com/r/w6zHSY/1)

Comment: much better! The only doubt is why do you put a double backslash, it is because we are in Java? I mean, in the page regex101 its only neccessary one backslash, for instance: \d{3} --> a three digit number

Comment: @user71209 Yes, other languages have regex literals and you can use only one slash but in Java, because we're using `String` literals, we have to escape the slash.